# SQL Do Except without knowing columns name and without names of columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, compare, except

I have to compare 2 sets, and in the process I must use `EXCEPT`, but `EXCEPT` doesn't exist in Microsoft ACCESS (at least 2010). So I know I can do this with `NOT IN` or doing an `LEFT JOIN`.

But to do this you must use columns names.

Unfortunately the software I have created (and rewrite for ACCESS) must compare table contents by name.

So it must work to compare:

Table A and Table B. If i do  `select * from A` i have 3 rows of INT
1
2
2

If i do `select * from B` i have 3 rows of INT
2
1
1

So there are the same if TABLE A is
1 A
2 B
2 B
and TABLE C is
2 B
1 A
2 B

It must be able to compare any TABLES who have same structure

What I want to do is the same as

```
select * from A 
EXCEPT 
select * from B
```

But I can't use columns name

Sincerely

Comment: I"m confused.  If you expect the except to work then the tables A,B must have the same structure, data types etc.  If that's true then I don't see how 1,2,2 and 2,1,1 are the same.  If string data the string compairson would fail.  If those are 3 different columns, then it would also fail as 2 <> 1

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . You can also use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to add sample data to your question. Please don't post code or data in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: I think you'll have to construct a dynamic SQL **with** column names in VBA. I don't see how this would be possible without the column names. You can get them from the `TableDef` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and it is sad that engineer from MicroSoft are less "clever" than the free developpers of sqlite (it is a joke of course).